# Can I add a class with spaces to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to add a fontawesome.com icon class ("fa fa-arrow-right")to a span in my website site but since it contains spaces I get an error. What can I do to fix this?

This is the error I get:

{
"message": "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('fa fa-arrow-right') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 13,
"colno": 21
}

```js
var arrowIcon = document.createElement("span");
arrowIcon.classList.add("fa fa-arrow-right");
document.getElementById("search-result-parent").appendChild(arrowIcon);
```

Comment: They mean two classes, fa and fa-arrow-right, not one class with a space.

Comment: `arrowIcon.className += " fa fa-arrow-right"`

Comment: For add multiple classes you need to replace this line "arrowIcon.classList.add("fa fa-arrow-right");" with this one "arrowIcon.className = "fa fa-arrow-right";

Comment: You need to use `classList.add("fa", "fa-arrow-right")` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you want to add more than one class that you need to comma separate them.

```
arrowIcon.classList.add("fa", "fa-arrow-right");
```

You can also do this using the spread operator:

```
const classNames = "fa fa-arrow-right":
arrowIcon.classList.add(...classNames.split(" "));
```